# Страница пользователя

Tags: php, html

Если страница принадлежит вошешдшему то ему выдаёться одно. Если нет то другое. Это у меняя сделано. А что делать если пользователь не вошел но перешол на страницу с id например 3 как сделать что бы ему тоже показали страницу пользователя.
Но он не может совершать ни каких действий
[Код страницы](http://fastunit.16mb.com/12.txt)

Зарание благодарю

Comment: нужно в сессию записывать id юзера.
если юзер перешол на страницу с id например 3 а его id 4(записан в сессии)... то он не может совершать ни каких действий.
если же юзер перешол на страницу с id например 3 и в его сессии тоже 3 то это его страница

Comment: Это всё у меня сделано .
У меня не получаеться. То что если пользователь не вошел как вк например ему всё равно показывали страницу. Я выше код даже показал. То что у меня написано

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо на скрипты, которые выполняют действия, добавить ту же проверку на наличие id и его страницы. т.е. , насколько я понял из Вашего кода, вам надо вставить в скрипты message.php exit.php и т.д. примерно тот же код что и в приведённом Вами. Если не его страничка - то выдавать или редиректить на страничку которая говорит об этом.

Comment: Нет у меня всё зделано когда страница принадлежит или нет.
Мне нужно если у человека нет страницы ,  а он например решил посмотреть страничку какого не будь человека .В адресную строку прописал в пример hashcode.ru/page?13. И он может увидить некоторые элементы страницы

Comment: Так что не понятно-то? Страница ему не принадлежит, она отображается, но действия он свершить не может т.к. на скриптах действий идёт проверка кто вызвал это действие